# Bootstrap model not showing up from selected option

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I Have a bootstrap form I'm trying to create and having problems with opening a model from a selected drop-down menu option.

I can get it to open with the button link next to it but it won't work in the drop-down menu. The other thing that's puzzling is it works in a jsfiddle but not on my site.

Any clues would be appreciated

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2tkv5mo/3/)

Here is my add_job.php(part file) can include rest if required

```
        <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_contractor">Select Contractor *</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="contractor" name="contractor" required="required" data-error="Contractor is required.">
                            <option value="">Please select contractor *</option>
                            <option value="addnewcon">Add new Contractor</option>
                            <?php  foreach ($all_contractors as $con): ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $con['ID'] ?>">
                                <?php echo $con['Name'] ?>
                              </option>
                             <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

      <!-- Modal -->
<div id="addnewcon" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem omnis aliquid voluptatibus, distinctio soluta eligendi officiis voluptatem necessitatibus magnam illum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_addnewcon"></label><BR><BR>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addnewcon">Add new</button>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
```

And here is the section of code from my functions.js

```
$("#contractor").change(function () {        
if($(this).val() == 'addnewcon'){
    $('#addnewcon').modal({show: true});
}});
```

**EDIT**

**Updated JS code**

So after working out the debug in my code, I can now get it to work in IE, Firefox but still not working in chrome

Comment: Well fiddle you mentioned above is working fine as you also mentioned. The only possibility of not working in your website is the environment must be different where you are using it. You can either post the website/environment link or can debug the code to see why it's not working.

Comment: Can you shared your website code or url?

Comment: I run the website on local machine as im only in the process of setting it up. I do use a WAMP server if thay makes any difference? Yes I admit im only a newbie but how do you debug the code to see?

Comment: Ok, so a little bit of a win, I figured out how to debug and I got it to work in firefox but cant get it to work in chrome. Any reason why that would be?